# display returning value from post

Tags: reactjs, laravel, breeze, use-form

I use Laravel + Breeze + React. In default this stack using "post" from useform. Standard example:

```
const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    post(route('register'));
};
```

But sometimes I need to return value from backed (for example with stored object or true\false value). How can I display returning value from backend? `.then(() => ...)` doesn;t work with `post()`. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try `Async` and `Await` instead?

Comment: Something like: `const submit = async (e) => { const response = await post(route('register'); console.log(response.json())) }` or maybe `console.log(await response.json())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `post` method is using Inertiajs.

You can use the `onSuccess` handler to grab the response data:

```js
post(route('register'), {
  onSuccess: (data) => console.log(data),
})
```

Learn more here: https://inertiajs.com/forms